# Are there instances that unreferenced JavaScript variables are not deleted from chrome?

Tags: javascript, memory

I was on chrome (a regular non-experimental version) making a sprite placing system and I found I could run `new Uint8ClampedArray(999999999)` 8 times by typing it in the console and the webpage and console would crash.

The error message given on the debug console was was "Debugging connection was closed. Reason: Render process gone. Reconnect when ready by reopening DevTools"

The error message given on the webpage was "Error code: SBOX_FATAL_MEMORY_EXCEEDED"

This is no doubt an error related to memory.

I did not reference any of the massive arrays I set.

Does chrome not delete unreferenced js variables or is something else going on.

Comment: "*Does chrome not delete unreferenced js variables or is something else going on.*" you still have to wait for garbage collection.

Comment: Well the garbage collector will eventually run, but you're allocating a lot of memory explicitly. Also, the `console` mechanism may hang onto one (or more) of the references created internally.

Comment: If there's some *realistic* situation in actual code that you're having problems with, you should ask about that directly. Things that happen in the console are not always relevant to actual code in a page.